# How to build packages for superset-ui?

Tags: apache-superset

https://github.com/apache-superset/superset-ui --- Git link to superset-ui repo

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Contributing.md](https://github.com/apache-superset/superset-ui/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)

It's a great resource for following how to build the source code and hack it.